# Storing & sharing music history between devices

Tags: android, audio-player, android-sharing, android-music-player

I am writing an Android app for uni (semester project). The idea is to be able to compare music "taste" between nearby devices. Long story short it's somewhat similar to Last.fm, but the idea is to be able to do similar things but for nearby devices, and not people all around the world, just like being able to see what the person at the end of your bus is listening to (if they're using my app of course) - seeing the currently playing/last played song on your, preferably using the Android player's list of most played songs to get some sort of comparision, perhaps also somehow extracitng "Artists" from the default Android player. I have two general questions:

**MAIN QUESTION** Finding nearby devices & getting it's IDs. I don't need a huge range on that, Bluetooth would be enough for the needs of the project but the thing is most of the functionalities will be handled via database, all I need is finding nearby devices and getting the device's unique ID (as a String, preferably hashed from MAC and ANDROID_ID, since the latter doesn't guarantee it will be unique). What would be the optimal & fairly easy way to do it so that I can find the device and after clicking on it I'd get just the ID? I've figured almost everything else in the app out but I have honestly no idea how to approach this - even though it seems to do very little, but is also a key thing to make my app what it is.

**SIDE QUESTION** When it comes to the "Artists" tab in default player - is there a way to extract the list of all artists of the songs (and the amount of the songs by them) that I have on my phone? You can see the songs grouped by artists in the player, but I didn't find a way to do what I described. It's not a necessary feature I'd like to include in the app but it would definitely be great to just have like a general idea that someone has 7 songs by Metallica on their phone.

Thanks in advance for any help, espescially with the first issue, but I'll appreciate if someone has an idea how to achieve what I described in the side question as well!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should first show us what have you tried so far before asking for help. See http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ for a good explanation.

Comment: Hey Selcuk - the question is more of the nature that I don't really know how to approach the search part. I didn't try to code anything yet because I don't know if using Bluetooth would be a good way to broadcast the device ID from my app to another devices with the same app. I've searched the web for for quite some time but I didn't find similar problems that would help me so I don't really know where to start in the first place.